# Nuxt doesn't execute `fetch()` when reloading page when deployed

Tags: nuxt.js, cicd

In my nuxt app I fetch data via the `fetch()` method. This works totally fine but as soon as I reload the page the data is gone and the `fetch()` method doesn't get executed. (Network tab doesn't show any request)

I'm using axios and vuex.

vuex store

```
// state
export const state = () => ({
  list: [],
})

// getters
export const getters = {
  getUsers(state){
    return state.list
  },
  getActiveUsers(state){
    return state.list.filter(user => user.user.is_active);
  }
}

// mutations
export const mutations = {
  SET_USERS(state, users){
    state.list = users
  },
}

// actions
export const actions = {
  async fetchUsers(context) {
    try {
      const data = await this.$axios.get(`/api/v1/user/`)
      data.data.forEach(user => {
        user.contrastColor = calculateContrastColor(user.color);
      })
      context.commit('SET_USERS', data.data)
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

page.vue

```
<script>

export default {
  computed: {
    users() {
      return this.$store.state.users.list
    }
  },
  fetch() {
    return this.$store.dispatch("users/fetchUsers");
  },
}
</script>
```

I chose the deployment server here's my gihub actions file:

```
name: Deployment

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["ci"]
    types:
      - completed

env:
  BASE_URL: http://mysupercoolbackendurl.com/

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup node env 
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3.0.0
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
          check-latest: true

      - name: Cache node_modules 
        uses: actions/cache@v2.1.7
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      - name: Install dependencies ‍
        run: npm ci --prefer-offline --no-audit

      - name: Build project 
        run: npm run build
      
      - name: Start server 
        run: | 
          pm2 restart mysupercoolservice
          sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Setting `fetchOnServer: false` didn't work.

Here are the versions I'm using:
nuxt@2.15.8
node v14.17.6

Answer (score 0):

If you find a solution, please post how you did it. If you have not found a solution yet, then try to make requests in fetch asynchronous. Like this:

```
  async fetch() {
    return await this.$store.dispatch("users/fetchUsers");
  }
```